# How to make custom associative array using an array with foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I have an orders array. Now I want to group array elements according to their `order_id`. Then I did like below...

```
$CompleteOrders = [];

        $OrderCount = 0;
        foreach($OrdersWithProductDetails as $OrdersWithProductDetail) {

            if(empty($CompleteOrders)) {
                $CompleteOrders[$OrderCount][$OrderCount] = $OrdersWithProductDetail;
            } else {
                for($i = 0; $i < count($CompleteOrders); $i++) {
                    if(isset($CompleteOrders[$i][$i])) {
                        if($CompleteOrders[$i][$i]->order_id == $OrdersWithProductDetail->order_id) {
                            $CompleteOrders[$i][$OrderCount+1] = $OrdersWithProductDetail;
                            //print_r($CompleteOrders);
                            $OrderCount++;
                        } else {
                            $CompleteOrders[$OrderCount+1][0] = $OrdersWithProductDetail;
//                        print_r($CompleteOrders);
                            $OrderCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
//                break;
            }

        }

        dd($CompleteOrders);
```

But, when I print the `$CompleteOrders` array, in first element(0) there are all the order details which is belongs to `order_id` 93. but, 
after that elements have different keys(3 and 4) even they has the same `order_id` like below.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▶]
  3 => array:1 [▶]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1268 ▼
      +"id": 102
      +"size": "30"
      +"order_quantity": "1"
      +"price": "798"
      +"created_at": "2020-06-16 19:24:00"
      +"updated_at": "2020-06-16 19:24:00"
      +"order_id": "94"
      +"owi_id": "255"
      +"item_id": "36"
      +"item_name": "Acc One"
      +"description": "Test"
      +"quantity": null
      +"main_fileimg": "1 (1).jpg"
      +"main_filepath": "assets/img/product/accessories/"
      +"main_category": "Accessories"
      +"category": "Denim"
      +"final_total_amount": "1593"
      +"cus_name": "Customer Name"
      +"tel_no": "123456789"
      +"email": "email@gmail.com"
      +"address_line_one": "Earth Rd"
      +"address_line_two": "Neptune"
      +"city": "Sun"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to create an array like below.

```
$Orders = 
    0 => [
         0 => "OrderId94"
              "Item"
         1 => "OrderId94"
              "Item"
],
    1 => [
         0 => "OrderId94"
              "Item"
         1 => "OrderId94"
              "Item"
]
```

** EDIT **

```
$OrdersWithProductDetails = DB::table('order_id_with_owi_ids')
            ->join('orders_with_items','orders_with_items.id','order_id_with_owi_ids.owi_id')
            ->join('item_id_with_owi_ids','item_id_with_owi_ids.owi_id','orders_with_items.id')
            ->join('products','products.item_id','item_id_with_owi_ids.item_id')
            ->join('item_with_main_categories','item_with_main_categories.item_id','products.item_id')
            ->select('orders_with_items.*', 'order_id_with_owi_ids.*', 'products.*')
            ->get();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try with  `$data = json_encode($CompleteOrders);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are overengineering

What about https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby

I think your `OrdersWithProductDetails` is a Laravel Collection you can use GroupBy to group them by the order_id

```
$grouped = $OrdersWithProductDetails->groupBy('order_id');
$grouped = $grouped->toArray();
dd($grouped);
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked perfectly !! 
And also I want to know, how can I get this without using groupBy. I mean using foreach or any other method ??

Comment: Well you can achieve the same result using plain arrays but that's not the laravel way, with collections you can do more interesting things

Comment: Okay, got it.. But, in my example, what am I doing wrong with that foreach and for loop ??